# Google deployment manager $. usage

Tags: google-deployment-manager

I wanted to know what `$.` refers to in Google deployment manager templates

[Reference 1](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/blob/982780bccc4ddcbf0b072b3d541a677cc0de4ab0/examples/v2/gke/python/cluster.py#L76)

[Reference 2](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/blob/982780bccc4ddcbf0b072b3d541a677cc0de4ab0/examples/v2/gke/python/cluster.py#L83)

What are the set of functions that be used along with `$.` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a way to dynamically put in values based on certain conditions, but there's no documentation on this particular syntax. I can see the "$." in [jinja configuration](https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/blob/master/components/gcp-click-to-deploy/src/configs/cluster.jinja#L214) and [MongoDB's documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) also shows the same concept; just that in Deployment Manager, it's $.ifNull ...

There are other set of functions that are used such as: $.resource, $.concat, etc. But again, we don't have a documented reference for the list.

Comment: I asked the same question on Github and got an answer- fyi
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/issues/212

Comment: I don't see much similarity between the two.